# Y-modem protocol frame count

Tags: stm32, uart

When I use the Y-modem protocol  on stm32 board, I’m faced with data count bytes. There are two bytes on the frame, one byte is data count another is 0xFF-dataCount.

```
SOH 01 FE data[] 1A...1A CRCH CRCL
```

But I have a question on the this process; When I send 128 byte every process, than 8 byte data get max "255" = 0xFF value, So If I try to transmit 256+ data, I will face with problem because the data count value have one byte.

Why the data count 1 byte on the Y modem frames? If we use the 255+ data count frame what can I do?

Comment: You can either send 128 byte packets starting with SOH, or 1024 byte packets starting with STX.

Comment: @gogogo There is no block size sent in Ymodem packet. Or açtually the first byte defines the packet size. What you are asking about is a block count number, a running counter which increases for each block.

Comment: block count sorry

Comment: So, If the block count byte equals = 00 and data include 1024 byte, Could we say the data count more than 255+ ?

Answer (score 1):

The block count increases by one each packet and it simply overflows and wraps around from 255 to 0. It reads in the YMODEM documentation.